# Pundit awarded by mistake?

Tags: bug, comment, badges

I just obtained the Pundit badge, so out of curiosity I wanted to have a look at the comments that were responsible for that. I used [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/27196/my-top-ranked-comments), and it turned out that only 6 comments have the required number of 5 votes.

Is there a flaw in the query, in my understanding of the badge, or is there an actual bug?

Comment: I somehow doubt that there's a bug in something that's been around for quite a while. As an alternative explanation I offer that SEDE queries use data that may be up to one week outdated. So may be some of your comments reached the limit only this week? May be you can wait for a couple of days and rerun the query?

Comment: @jyrki I checked some of the comments with 4 and they were up to date. But yes, I will try again in a couple of days.

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Hmm...

Comment: [Another possibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163502/169003): Comments on deleted posts count towards Pundit, but don't show in that query.

Comment: @Jyrki It may be the point, good catch!

Comment: Arnaud, it happens that  pundit comes from the Hindi word Pandit. Have you been to India recently?